# Not able to disable `compilerOptions: noUnusedLocals` and `compilerOptions: noUnusedParameters` in vscode

Tags: typescript

I'm using `@typescript-eslint` to manage unused locals & params and therefore want to disable TypeScript from throwing duplicate warnings.

Here's are my configs.

```json
// tsconfig.base.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Expo",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },

  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",

  // default values are here  https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "esnext",
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "paths": { "~/*": ["./*"] }
  }
}
```

But with those settings, I still get 6133 warnings from TS.

[image: unused locals]

[image: unused params]

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Did you find out the cause for that?

Comment: Sadly, no. Post an answer if you figure it out!

Comment: No. Never got this one solved.